# How to Right align a web part?

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have a page that I need to right align a web part at the top of the page. Not the text itself I just need the web part to be on the right side instead of the left side.

I cannot change the layout as much of the rest of the page would then no longer be correct.

How do I make a web part align to the right?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "you cannot change the layout."  You cannot edit the .aspx page?

Comment: @BrandonC. It would mess up the other formatting I have on the page if I changed the base web layout on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IE then press F12 to get start the developer tools and select the web part. You can then see the class tags where you can try to change the alignment/location.

You need to check for the webpart ID which will be something like this "MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2"

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes but wouldn't that only change it for me? As soon as I leave the page it would reset correct?

Comment: You need to write the code inside a <script> tag and then use it inside a Content Editor web part.

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked 'Right to left' in webpart settings:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

select the webpart and change the `<script>` in edit html sorce option available in the ribbon